# Hiding countdown field on 0 and show other field / fields

Tags: entities

Can you help me with this? I'm using conditional fields and it hides other field only on node edit form. I've also tried the field formatter conditions but there's no such an option... Thanks for help

Comment: Please edit your question and make it *clear* what have you tried, what the desired effect is, what you got and what exactly you wanted to ask about. This is Q&A, not a support forum. And please remember - you know all your situation. We only know what you actually wrote here. Read it as if you didn't know anything. See my point?